# Tkinter - How to go to the top of a Treeview when pressing down at the bottom, and vice versa?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

```
tree = ttk.Treeview(root, selectmode="browse")
tree.pack()
```

When a user presses the Down arrow key while they have the last item selected already, I need it to select the top item, and the same for the Up arrow. Thanks!

Comment: have you read through the treeview documentation and tried anything? Methods for scrolling around are all documented.

Comment: I see nothing that can do this. Could you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `bind()` function to key `Down` (`Up`) in `TreeView` which will check if you are in last (first) row and jump to first (last) row. It will have to move selection, move focus, scroll window and block event so TreeView will not use this key to move to next (previous) row.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def jump_to_first(event):
    last = tree.get_children()[-1]
    if tree.focus() == last:
        first = tree.get_children()[0]
        tree.selection_set(first) # move selection
        tree.focus(first) # move focus
        tree.see(first) # scroll to show it
        return "break" # don't send event to TreeView

def jump_to_last(event):
    first = tree.get_children()[0]
    if tree.focus() == first:
        last = tree.get_children()[-1]
        tree.selection_set(last) # move selection
        tree.focus(last) # move focus
        tree.see(last) # scroll to show it
        return "break" # don't send event to TreeView

root = tk.Tk()

tree = ttk.Treeview(root, selectmode="browse")
tree.pack()

for x in range(1, 21):
    print(tree.insert('', 'end', text=str(x)))

tree.bind('<Down>', jump_to_first)
tree.bind('<Up>', jump_to_last)

root.mainloop()
```